# dynamic input and select how to build queryString

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a `query parameter` for when doing a search, I managed to build it with `input` field however there's a `select` dropdown menu to select other values.

```
<input type="text" class="dd">
<select name="" class="sel">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Prepare">Prepare</option>
  <option value="Ready">Ready</option>
  <option value="Cancel">Cancel</option>
</select>

<button onclick="buildQuery()">Build query</button>
```

jQuery code for query building the query param

```
function buildQuery(){
  var result = "?";
  var getVal = $('input.dd').val();
  console.log('Input > ', getVal);
  var getSelectVal = $('select.sel').val();
  if (getVal != null && (getVal != "")) {
    let inputValues = getVal
    .split("\n")
    .filter(function (str) { return str !== "" })
    .join("&test=");
    // then add it to the overall query string for all searches
    result = result + 'test' + "=" + inputValues + "&";

    console.log('Results > ', result);
  }
```

Not sure how can I get the value from the `select` and construct it similar way to my input console.log output `Results >  ?test=f&`

So if you fill in the `input` and `select` an option it the queryParam should say something like `?test=inputVal&test=selectVal` or individual `?test=inputVal` or `?test=selectVal`

What I can do is copy the whole `if()` statement and replace the `getVal` with `getSelectVal` but it seems inefficient and duplicating the code.

**Actual code --**

```
newSearchParams.properties.forEach(function (inputSearch) {
        // first reparse the input values to individual key value pairs
        // Checks which field is not null and with empty string (space)
        var getVal = $('input.input_' + inputSearch.name).val();
        var getSelectVal = $('select.select_' + inputSearch.name).val();
        if (getVal != null && (getVal != "")) {
            let inputValues = getVal
                .split("\n")
                .filter(function (str) { return str !== "" })
                .join("&" + inputSearch.name + "=");
            // then add it to the overall query string for all searches
            result = result + inputSearch.name + "=" + inputValues + "&";
        }
    }, this);
    // remove trailing '&'
    result = result.slice(0, result.length - 1);
    return result;
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wdecqe9/7/)

Edit: -- This is what I'm trying to get out of this question,

```
if(paramMethod == 'path'){
 // build parameter api/id/1
} else if(paramMethod =='query'{
 // build queryString api/apiPoint?id=1
} else if(paramMethod == 'none') {
 // var result = "";
 // return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not worrying about IE < 9:

```
function buildQuery() {
  return $('.dd, .sel')
    .toArray()
    .reduce(function(str, el) {
      return str + (el.value ? el.name + '=' + el.value + '&' : '')
    }, '?')
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qk3d7bq1/2/

If you care about IE < 9:

```
function buildQuery() {
  var query = '?'
  $('.dd, .sel').each(function() {
    if (this.value) {
      query += this.name + '=' + this.value + '&'
    }
  })
  return query
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d51f5uyw/2/

---

Update

If you want to make this generically useful, just pass a selector string to buildQuery to select the exact things you want:

```
function buildQuery(selector) {
  return $(selector)
    .toArray()
    .reduce(function(str, el) {
      return str + (el.value ? el.name + '=' + el.value + '&' : '')
    }, '?')
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qsxkz4qu/1/

Alternatively you could specify a container and have buildQuery find all of the form fields inside that container:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uar5h3xe/1/

But buildQuery itself should not be defining any selection variables. That's configuration that should be passed to it.

---

Update

If you want to parameterize the whole thing, you could use something like what's shown at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uar5h3xe/4/

Comment: both are returning `undefined`, can you make a jsfiddle with the answer?

Comment: Well, that function was just returning the query string value. You'd want another function that your button triggers that will call buildQuery and make use of it. See the fiddles for examples where I'm just logging the output to the console. You'd want to do something else with it, of course.

Comment: Thanks, instead of using `$('.dd, .sel')` can I use variable instead? like the issue I mentioned in my question like
`$('input.input_'+inputSearch.name, 'select.select_'+inputSearch.name)` this instead

Comment: Updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late reply to your answer. The last fiddle works but I need to pass specific `el.name` like `id, name` or in my case if you see my `forEach()` I'm passing `inputSearch.name` to construct something like `?id=val&sku=val`

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass the input names if you pass the selectors. You can pass any selector you want that would work with jQuery and it will get the elements, which means you get the names and values in the loop. I'm not seeing how manually passing in the names adds any value.

Comment: Got it, so what if I want to pass `api/id/1` so its parameter rather than queryString?

Comment: You would just change the part of the function that builds the string to output that format, eg: ```query += this.name + '/' + this.value + '/'``` and have the variable start with a /: ```var query = '/'```

Comment: I've edited my original question, added what I'm trying to get out of this. Do I have to return the same thing as the queryString just different `.reduce()` variable? Mind updating the fiddle/answer above?

Comment: Updated my answer with a new fiddle

Comment: That's a clean code, though from trying to understand it that's specifying which `container` has `queryParam` or `queryString`, right? What if you don't know which is one `queryParam or queryString` That's why my `if()` condition is like that.

Comment: The container is the element (form, fieldset, div, whatever) that's holding the fields you want to reduce to a string.

Comment: You would either write a function for each button that needs to submit a form and have the string output determined there, or you could add a data- attribute to the container that specifies the output type and get that from the container